# Which DI version supports a non core EF

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, msbuild

I am using NET framework 4.6.1 and I found DependencyInjection 1.0  deprecated. I would like to know which version I should upgrade DI to that will make it compatible to  non core EF.

I have tried 6.0 and 3.0, but got built error on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the NuGet page for [DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/6.0.0) 6.0 is targeted to .NET Framework 4.6.1, so between version 1.0 and 6.0 are probably breaking changes. If you have build errors, then you have to solve them.